# Amazon SQS, Boto, and Python: Fetching and Running a Script on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto

I am trying to run a set of python scripts on Amazon EC2. This [help guide](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-S3/3998) suggests using Amazon SQS to manage a queue. From this guide, I understand how to boot up an EC2 instance and send a job to the queue from my computer, but I do not understand how to set up the EC2 instance such that it will run the python script after it is fetched from the queue and then save the result to Amazon S3. How do I fetch, run on the EC2 server, and save the results to S3 of a python script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the mentioned guide you can find a link to a [github repository](https://github.com/paltman/django-pdf) with sample code. This is a working example, answering your question. It is well documented and easy to read.

Namely, look closer on [pdf/tasks.py](https://github.com/paltman/django-pdf/blob/master/pdf/tasks.py) source code. In short, it use `ec2.run_instances` to startup ec2 instance with a bootstrap bash script that:

- updates instance with `apt-get`
- in a loop uses `boto.connect_sqs` to connect to SQS and fetch a task
- performs task
- uses `boto.connect_s3()` to connect to S3 and upload results
- shutdowns instance when script finishes.

**UPDATE**

Moreover, `CheckResponseQueueTask` is a good example of pereodic dequeuing messages with `Celery.PeriodicTask` from `SQS` and processing them. Look `BOOTSTRAP_SCRIPT`, source lines 51-57, for sample code illustrating results uploading to S3. And `CheckQueueLevelsTask` illustrates new instance booting and bootstraping with queue processor, in case of amount of tasks exceeding number of instances. Lines 214-244 for reference.

Comment: Your update is extremely helpful alko. I believe I now understand how this script you link to boots instances, retrieves tasks from the queue, and saves to S3, but where is the task the newly booted instance performs in-between? Is it lines 160-173, simply transferring the file to a particular S3 bucket? If I wanted to add an additional task to perform before saving to S3, say taking x from the queue and saving the result of a f(x) to S3, how/where would I add this to the code?

Comment: You might want to copy the code from the link into your answer and add your annotation so your answer does not die if the link dies. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: All the code executed on new instance is written in `BOOTSTRAP_SCRIPT`. **It is `bash` script!** Magic (data processing) happens with `subprocess.Popen`, on lines 99-104. See that this script is run with `python -c` syntax (21) in loop (75), and when no data is fetched for 10 consecutive times with delay of 10 secs, it ends (81), and system is shut down (125). Ref line numbers in brakes.

Comment: There are 18 forks on git, and one mine ;) There is a lot of code, I don't think it's appropriate to copy all here.

Comment: And script is run with a magic line 242 `user_data=startup`, arument to `boto.ec2.run_instances`. In fact, I wasn't aware about this functionality, and found it useful :)

Comment: Ok, so any function previously defined within `BOOTSTRAP_SCRIPT` can obviously be called within the script as well, which is run on the EC2 instance. Still need to work through the entire script and modify it for my own purposes, but this finally makes sense! Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 2):

One way to so this would be to run [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) on your EC2 instance which is able to use AWS SQS as a task broker out of the box.

Information on using Celery and AWS SQS can be found here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html

Celery also supports concurrency and multiple workers. This means you can have multiple EC2 instances running Celery listening to the one AWS SQS queue and the tasks will distribute themselves among your instances automatically.

Comment: Celery seems like it would be a huge help. The documentation, however, is broken up into each little part of the program and I am having a hard time piecing it all together. Can you provide or point me to annotated sample code that fetches from Amazon SQS, runs a function with the input from SQS/S3 and then saves the output to S3. Ideally, the code would also boot the EC2 instance.

Comment: Look in the mentioned code, celery is used to run async tasks, https://github.com/paltman/django-pdf/blob/master/pdf/tasks.py. In fact, `CheckResponseQueueTask` is a sample code of periodic messages dequeuing and processing. Updated my answer accordingly